# Make the system wait for a file to be created

Tags: javascript

my code works, however, it is skipping a few steps.

Code:

```js
link = message.body.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ')
    if(palavraChave == '/musica'){
      apiDownload.downloadAudio(link)
      await client.sendFile(message.from, 'C:/Users/mathe/Desktop/wpp/videos/musica.mp3', 'musica')
      await fs.unlinkSync('C:/Users/mathe/Desktop/wpp/videos/musica.mp3')
    }
```

Código apiDownload:

```js
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const fs = require('fs')

downloadAudio = (link)=>{
    ytdl(link).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`videos/musica.mp3`), console.log('criado!'))
}

exports.downloadAudio = downloadAudio;
```

This code above, downloads the audio perfectly and puts it in a folder on my computer, however, when I try to send this audio that was created, the system says that it does not exist.

Note: If I run it again, then it finds the file and sends it.

That is, the problem is that the system does not wait for me to create the file and already wants to send it.

How can I make the system wait for me to create the file in my folder, after it has been created, send it?

And, after sending delete.

Can someone help me please.

I'm a beginner.

Comment: I don't know where `apiDownload.downloadAudio(link)` comes from, but it's certainly asynchronous, and you don't wait for it to complete before executing `sendFile`. If it returns a Promise, you can add `await` in front of it. Otherwise, maybe it allows for a callback?

Comment: where is you async keyword? Add more code

Comment: Look for more code, see if it's clear

Comment: @MatheusNascimento did you try to put the await suggested by blex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be able to know when the file is downloaded. For this, it would be useful to make `downloadAudio` return a Promise. You should be able to edit it like this:

```
downloadAudio = link => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const stream = ytdl(link, { filter: "audioonly" })
                     .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`videos/musica.mp3`));
    stream.on("error", reject);
    stream.on("finish", () => { console.log("criado!"); resolve(); });
  });
};
```

And then, in your main function, add `await` in front of it:

```
await apiDownload.downloadAudio(link);
```

Comment: Deixei como comentou, porém o sistema trava.

Coloquei console.log para ver onde para, e está parando no '1'.

```js
    if(palavraChave == '/musica'){
      console.log('1')
      await apiDownload.downloadAudio(link)
      console.log('2')
      await client.sendFile(message.from, 'C:/Users/mathe/Desktop/wpp/videos/musica.mp3', 'musica')
      console.log('3')
      await fs.unlinkSync('C:/Users/mathe/Desktop/wpp/videos/musica.mp3')
      console.log('4')
    }
```

Comment: @MatheusNascimento Sorry, I messed things up. I edited the code for `downloadAudio`. Does it work better? Note that I added `{ filter: 'audioonly' }` to actually get an mp3, and not a video